# Refresh iframe when hosted on different server

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

I have a simple quiz that's in an iframe on my client's website. Unfortunately the quiz is hosted on a different server to my client's site. The client wants the content of the iframe to refresh 60 seconds after the user submits a form (easily done), but whenever I try to get the quiz to refresh itself, the browser blocks it for security reasons  - they're on different domains.

I'm not trying to alter the parent window destination, just reload the iframe itself, so hopefully security isn't an issue...  but I've tried `iframe.contentWindow.history.back();` but I'm still getting the same security error:

> Uncaught SecurityError: Blocked a frame with origin
>   "http://www.ourserver.com" from accessing a frame with origin
>   "http://www.clientserver.com". Protocols, domains, and ports must
>   match.

How can I get the iframe to refresh itself? Is this possible? Or does the browser consider the iframe to be owned by the parent page, and so won't even let me refresh it? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can only do a workaround using message posting, the direct manipulation is blocked for a good reason by all browsers.

In your main page:

```
var frame = document.getElementById('your-frame-id');

frame.contentWindow.postMessage("reload please, thank you", '*');
```

In your  (contained in the main page):

```
window.addEventListener('message', function(event) {
  if (event.data === "reload please, thank you") {
      location.reload();
    }
});
```